# Condition in Mathematica to accept list of pairs with numeric input

Tags: list, wolfram-mathematica, conditional-statements

I am trying to create a function in Mathematica that takes in a list of pairs that are numeric and outputs a list of the first element of the pair raised to the inverse power of the second element e.g. {{1,3},{2,2}....} -> {1^(1/3),2^(1/2),...}.

This is what I have got so far:

```
pairsToRoots3[list : {{_, _} ..}] := 
list /. {p_Real, q_Real} :> p^(1/q)
```

It doesn't seem to work with p_Real but if i put p_Integer it works fine. Not sure why. Ideally, I would like the condition to be expressed like

```
 pairsToRoots3[list : {{_Real, _Real} ..}]
```

or somehting like this but everything I tried seemed not to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works if your numbers have head `Real`:

```
pairsToRoots[list : {{_Real, _Real} ..}] :=  #^(1/#2) & @@@ list

pairsToRoots[{{1`, 3`}, {2`, 2`}}]
```

> ```
> {1., 1.41421}
> ```

But these numbers do not have head `Real`:

```
Head /@ {1, 2, Pi 7/8}
```

> ```
> {Integer, Integer, Integer, Symbol, Rational}
> ```

Therefore you probably want `NumericQ` as george used:

```
pairsToRoots[list : {{_?NumericQ, _?NumericQ} ..}] :=  #^(1/#2) & @@@ list

pairsToRoots[{{1, 3}, {2, 2}}]
```

> ```
> {1, Sqrt[2]}
> ```

Answer (score 1):

```
f[{x_,y_}/;NumericQ[x]&&NumericQ[y]&&x>0&&y!=0]:=x^(1/y)
h[list_List]:=f/@list

h[{{1,2},{3,4}}]->{1,3^1/4}
```

personally i wouldn't bother to define "h",  but simply apply f as needed..

Answer (score 0):

Something like :

```
p2R[listOfPairs_] := #[[1]]^(1/#[[2]]) & /@ listOfPairs

p2R[{{a1, a2}, {b1, b2}, {c1, c2}}]
(* {a1^(1/a2), b1^(1/b2), (c1^((1/c2)))} *)
```

Alternatively :

```
MapThread[#1^(1/#2) &, Transpose[{{a1, a2}, {b1, b2}, {c1, c2}}]] 
(* {a1^(1/a2), b1^(1/b2), c1^(1/c2)} *)
```